# German and Indian word not detecting in google speech recognition with language code "en"

Tags: google-translate, google-speech-api

I am using google speech recognition API (@google-cloud/speech)
to transcribe speech 
below is my code

```
 const speech = require('@google-cloud/speech');

    const client = new speech.SpeechClient(
        {
              projectId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
              keyFilename: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.json'
        }
    );  
    const fileName = './resources/audio_file.wav';

    // Reads a local audio file and converts it to base64
    const file = fs.readFileSync(fileName);
    const audioBytes = file.toString('base64');

    // The audio file's encoding, sample rate in hertz, and BCP-47 language code
    const audio = {
      content: audioBytes,
    };
    const config = {
      encoding: 'LINEAR16',
      //sampleRateHertz: 16000,
      languageCode: "en",
    };
    const request = {
      audio: audio,
      config: config,
    };
```

the issue is when there is word "Koenig" my company name (german word) or any Indian name the speech API always print it wrong

I need to know is there any way I can feed these words (Indian name & some german words) to google speech recognition associated with my account so it detects correctly

Comment: I haven't tried, but you might be able to do it with [speech adaptation](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/context-strength#speech_adaptation). "Cloud Speech-to-Text includes a very large vocabulary. However, if proper names or domain-specific words are out-of-vocabulary, you can add them to the phrases provided to your the `speechContexts` in your request."

Comment: thanks this was exactly I was looking for